# Detect a collision in python - like isPointInPath

Tags: python, collision-detection, mesh

I am just generating a simple code of a mesh for signal disposition.

Here is an example of a mesh general shape:

```
domain = Rectangle(Point(0.0, 0.0), Point(1.0, 1.0))
```

Later I am generating circle coordinates, not touching directly boundaries with this piece of code:

```
xN = random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
yN = random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)
circ = Circle(Point(xN, yN), 0.1)
```

Inside of a "domain" I am placing these circles.

Place one of a circle is not a problem, but place more require to calculate collision between each of them.

I tried to use isPointInPath script, but it is okay for a point, but not a circle (shape) I need to use and calculate.

So in general I have to:
 - create a shape (later used as a mesh)
 - generate circle and subtract it from shape
 - generate another circle and IF it is not collide, subtract it from subtracted shape
- and so on...

Because I do not want to generate circles into infinity (when there will be no space inside shape without holes), I just stop it after 3 times of "no success of collision detection".

What simple function or way should I use to reach my effect. I tried many things, but my way is more simple (objects are not moving).

Answer (score 0):

If the location and radius of the circle is known, test a candidate point for being within the radius of the circle by the distance equation (sqrt( (delta x squared) + (delta y squared))